# pygames / drawing circle that bounces off walls

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
b1 = {'rect':pygame.Rect(300, 80, 50, 100), 'color':RED, 'dir':UPRIGHT}
b2 = {'rect':pygame.Rect(200, 200, 20, 20), 'color':GREEN, 'dir':UPLEFT}
b3 = {'rect':pygame.Rect(100, 150, 60, 60), 'color':BLUE, 'dir':DOWNLEFT}
b4 = {'rect':pygame.draw.circle((300, 50), 20, 0,), 'color':PURPLE, 'dir':DOWNRIGHT}
blocks = [b1, b2, b3]


# draw the block onto the surface
pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, b['color'], b['rect'])
pygame.draw.circle(windowSurface, b['color'], (300, 50), 20, 0)
```

Brand new to pygames (programming in general). This is one of our first assignments, to edit a simple program that bounces squares off the walls. We are to add a circle but I'm not able to figure out how to fit it into the pre-existing dict structure for the rectangles. I'm getting the following error, what am I not seeing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CA115\Downloads\animation1.py", line 32, in <module>
    b4 = {'rect':pygame.draw.circle((300, 50), 20, 0,), 'color':PURPLE, 'dir':DOWNRIGHT}
TypeError: function takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

[A quick look at Pygame's documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) shows that you are providing less parameters than expected. In general, that's all Python is telling you when it said "TypeError: function takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)".

A little more detail: In line 32, as your error trace specifies, what causes the problem is the dictionary entry `'rect':pygame.draw.circle((300, 50), 20, 0,)`. From the documentation I linked, you should be able to figure out what went wrong here.

Another hint. Since you said that you are new to programming in general, you should note that the parameters for `pygame.Rect` and `pygame.draw.circle` have a significant difference: `Rect` takes in all primitive Python values ("numbers") while `circle` needs a particular *object*.